# Adding double quotes to NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, formatting

I have reading everything and \" does NOT work.

I am trying to create a string that looks like this:

"SomeString" = "AnotherString"

Here is the code that I have to insert the double quotes:

```
NSString *newOutput = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ \" = \" %@", output, [englishDic objectForKey:str]];
```

All that it outputs is:

```
"RateThisAppDontAsk \" = \" Don't ask again"
```

I thought maybe the "=" was causing problems but removing still gives me an output of this:

```
"RateThisAppDontAsk \"  \" Don't ask again"
```

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: What are the two strings you're providing as parameters, `output` and `[englishDic objectForKey:str]`?

Comment: All day I've been writing JSON strings with `\"` for the quotes surrounding names and strings.  Xcode must have broken sometime in the past 20 minutes.

Comment: It's hard to see how the output you claim could possibly have come from the format string you provide. For example, to produce `\"` in the output, the format string would have to contain `\\\"`.

Comment: @Caleb Both of the strings are simple strings, "Red" "Blue". I don't know how possible it was coming up with that output as well. I've put double quotes in strings before so I know it works, what I have seems as though it should work fine but it doesn't (why I came here).

Comment: @HotLicks I've used \" a million times before as well and it usually works. This however obviously doesn't and I had no idea why. Guess Xcode did break in the last 20 min.

Comment: You were clearly missing half the quotes.  (And the supposed output you posted is not from the code you posted, so likely you confused yourself badly trying to fix things.)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Works for me in a little MacOS X command line test program. Here's all the code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSString *newOutput = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ \" = \" %@", @"foo", @"bar"];
        NSLog(newOutput);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
test[54844:403] foo " = " bar
```

If you want quotes before *foo* and after *bar*, add those:

```
NSString *newOutput = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\"%@\" = \"%@\"", @"foo", @"bar"];
```

New output is:

```
test[54873:403] "foo" = "bar"
```

Comment: You are missing the other two desired double-quotes.

Comment: @rmaddy I just meant to show that escaping the quotation marks does work, contrary to what the OP says. However, the OP's format string is wrong if they want both strings quoted, as you point out, so I added a corrected format string and sample output.

Comment: I just ended up doing a different output format. Your format '@"\"%@\" = \"%@\"", @"foo", @"bar"]' doesn't work for me copied verbatim. It must be an issue with stringWithFormat?

Comment: @random You should be able to compile the code I provided into a test application and get the same output. If that much works, then the problem is in your project somewhere. I'd start looking for categories on `NSString` that might try to redefine `-stringWithFormat:`. In any case, try to reproduce the problem in a little test app like this one and make sure you get the right output.

Answer (score 4):

```
 NSString *output = @"RateThisAppDontAsk";
 NSString *nextString = @"Don't ask again";

 NSString *newOutput = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\"%@\" = \"%@\"", output, nextString];
 NSLog(@"%@",newOutput);
```

**Output**

```
"RateThisAppDontAsk" = "Don't ask again"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to do

```
NSString *firstObject = @"RateThisAppDontAsk";
NSString *secondObject = @"Don't ask again";
NSString *newOutput = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\"%@\" = \"%@\"",firstObject,secondObject];
```

Output

```
test[4556:c07] "RateThisAppDontAsk" = "Don't ask again"
```